# Read from file then use for to split fields but honor quotes

Tags: bash, for

This what I am trying to get in a bash shell script:

```
for a in "1" "2 3" "4 5 6"
do
  echo "a: $a"
done
a: 1
a: 2 3
a: 4 5 6
```

But the quotes are treated differently when you use a variable:

```
echo "\"1\" \"2 3\" \"4 5 6\"" > a.txt

cat a.txt
"1" "2 3" "4 5 6"

read aline < a.txt
```

If you double-quote the variable, you get this:

```
for b in "$aline"
do
  echo "b: $b"
done
b: "1" "2 3" "4 5 6"
```

And without quotes you get this:

```
for b in $aline
do
  echo "b: $b"
done
b: "1"
b: "2
b: 3"
b: "4
b: 5
b: 6"
```

Is there a way to get the for to process the contents of the variable as in the first example?

Comment: Is there _another_ issue that makes you ask this question? Do you have another problem that requires you to disable the shell's standard quote removal, which happens during the evaluation of a command?

Comment: @Kusalananda yeah, the OP said something to the effect that they simplified the example too much and here were the real thing, but it was cut short at the ":", and the message was immediately deleted. Let's hope that nothing bad happened to him <;-\

Comment: This is my first time posting a question on this forum, so working out my bugs around posting/commenting. The first answer I got from mosvy gave me enough to work out a solution. The "set -- " seemed to be losing fields. It doesn't like having '#Mi' (no quotes) as one of the fields but once I realized that, I just ran it through sed and now I'm getting what I want. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @LinusHicks If you're happy with one or several of the answers, upvote them.  If one is solving your issue, [accepting it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) would be the best way of saying "Thank You!"  Accepting an answer also indicates to _future_ readers that the answer actually solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you're OK with having the whole package (variable/arithmetic/command expansion, globbing, etc) on top of quote processing, this will do:

```
echo '"a b" "x         y"' >a.txt

eval "set -- $(<a.txt)"
for b do
    printf 'b: %s\n' "$b"
done

b: a b
b: x         y
```

Change the `$(<a.txt)` to `$(cat a.txt)` if you want it to work in a regular shell, not just `bash` (or other advanced shells like `zsh` or `ksh`). You could only use this if you're sure you can control the content of `a.txt`, otherwise it will be trivial to exploit your script via splitting with `;`, command expansion, etc.

However, if you just want to pass those arguments to a command, you can use `xargs`, which will just process the quotes, without doing any expansion:

```
xargs <a.txt printf 'b: %s\n'
```

But `xargs` will only work with external commands, not with shell functions, will ignore backslashes inside double quotes just like inside single quotes, and won't be able to parse multiline strings.

If these latter limitations are OK, you can still use `xargs` as a quote parser via a wrapper or an array:

```
mapfile -t args < <(xargs <a.txt printf '%s\n')
for b in "${args[@]}"; do
        printf 'b: %s\n' "$b"
done
```

Comment: Note that `$(<...)` is a ksh operator, copied by zsh and bash (though bash still forks a process, so only save the `cat` _execution_ there when using it). See [Understanding Bash's Read-a-File Command Substitution](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/368663) for details.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas included both suggestions.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas no, it's not: `printf '"a\nb" c' | xargs` => `xargs: unterminated quote`, `xargs: unmatched double quote, etc`. Also the standard says: A string of zero or more
     non-double-quote ( '"') characters and **non- <newline>** characters can
     be quoted by enclosing them in double-quotes. Same thing for single quotes.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right, for `xargs` a newline is quoted with backslash only. I forgot about that, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If instead of `bash` you're using `ksh93` (`ksh93` is the shell `bash` tries to mimic anyway), you could use the `-S` option of its `read` builtin which is to read csv (so understands csv-style quoting):

```
IFS=" " read -rSA array < a.txt
printf 'a: %s\n' "${array[@]}"
```

With `zsh`, you could use it's `z` parameter expansion flag which is used to tokenise the content of a variable as if it was `zsh` code (and so understand quoting as `zsh` would, but not do the code evaluation that `eval` would do) along with the `Q` parameter expansion flag to remove one layer of quoting:

```
IFS= read -r line < a.txt
printf 'a: %s\n' "${(Q@)${(z)line}}"
```

(the `@` parameter expansion flag is to preserve empty elements, reminiscent of `ksh`'s `${array[@]}` behaviour).

If `a.txt` contains more than one line, with `zsh` you can replace the `read` command with `content=$(<a.txt)` and with `ksh93` use `read` in a `while` loop (each `read` invocation potentially reading more than one line if a quoted string spans several line).